# Different datasource on one item in ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ListBox bound to a data context that works fine. But on some items I want to show a textblock with data from another context. But I cant get it to work. I had it working on a string in the cs class, but when I changed it to a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged i dont get the text to show at all...

This is a simplified ItemTemplate of my xaml:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ArrivalFlightItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrivalFlightItem.Operator}" />
            <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FlightDisclaimerConverter}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisclaimerText}" Style="{StaticResource NormalText}" Foreground="{StaticResource DarkForegroundColor}">
                    <TextBlock.DataContext>
                        <local:FlightDisclaimerItem/>
                    </TextBlock.DataContext>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In the cs constructor I have:

```
        var flightsVM = SingletonClass.FlightsViewModel;
        this.DataContext = listFlightsVM;
        disclaimerItem = new FlightDisclaimerItem();
        disclaimerItem.DisclaimerText = Strings.FlightInfoDisclaimerShort;
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out (I'm new to Windows Phone)?

Comment: You're setting the TextBlock's DataContext to an empty (new) FlightDisclaimerItem. Which I guess is the problem. It just doesn't have a value assigned to its DisclaimerText property. Also, more code and an explanation of the desired end result might help us give you better ideas. :)

Comment: But I'm setting the value in 
    disclaimerItem.DisclaimerText = Strings.FlightInfoDisclaimerShort;
Its the string I want to show. Or am I missing something?
The idea is to show some extra info in the last item of the list. I also have a button there to show more text (which the observable is for, I just replace the text with a longer one) 
The list is long so it didnt work putting it in a scrollview with text block after. So what I tried was to include the text in all items, but hide it in all but the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you binding some of your data in your code-behind? You should do it all in XAML.

- Define disclaimerItem as a property in your ViewModel.
- Set the name for your PhoneApplicationPage
- Use the PhoneApplicationPage Name in your markup extension to bind the textblock in question to the ViewModel property

`<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding DataContext.DisclaimerItemProperty, ElementName=phoneApplicationPageName}" />`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! I couldnt get it to work using another DataContext in the DataTemplate. But by binding to another object in the page (disclaimer panel) it works as intended.

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=DisclaimerPanel, Path=DataContext.DisclaimerText}"
```

Comment: That is essentially what I proposed. I'm just omitting the Path property of Binding, by using its default constructor which takes a single parameter for the path.